# How to change name or control App.config in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a chance how can I modify App.config file?

I have built setupwizard.msi but when I install the application in application folder it has created two files. One App.exe and App.exe.config

Is it because I have authentication into application with 'remember me' option to save credentials? These credentials are saved in AppData but even though it stores and takes credentials from that App.exe.config looks like this

```
 > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="userSettings" 
    type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
  <section name="App.Properties.Settings" 
    type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, 
    Version=4.0.0.0, 
    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
    allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
 </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup>
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source = |SQL/CE|" />
  </connectionStrings>
<userSettings>
 <App.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="userName" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="userPass" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="Remme" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="ipAddress" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
</App.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>
```

I definetly don't need another file like that and also I can't leave it app.exe.config. Can I change location of this file or handle it somehow?

Comment: This is maybe a little bit off-topic but do you really want to store a password in plain Text?

Comment: No no password are ecrypted/decrypted. @LittleBit

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the App config naming convention is driven by the framework.  So when you start an exe the framework can easily and consistently access the config file.